# shiny renderRadialNetwork fails to render graph

Tags: r, shiny

The below shiny app fails to render the Network graph. Whereas with an Rmd file I do get the graphic. Below an reproducible example. Keen to know where the error is if any.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(networkD3)
library(data.tree)
library(tidyr)

# Define UI for application that draws a network graph
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("slate"),
     sliderInput("number",
                 "Random Numbers:",
                 min = 1,
                 max = 100,
                 value = 20),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  radialNetworkOutput("radial")
  )

 # Define server logic required to draw a network graph 
 server <- function(input, output) {

 Data_tree <- reactive({
  data.frame(Start="Class",
                Asset = sample(c("FI","Equity","Currency"),input$number,replace = TRUE),
                Sub_Asset = sample(c("Asia","Europe","USA"),input$number,replace = TRUE),
                 Ticker = replicate(input$number,paste0(sample(LETTERS,3),collapse=""))) %>% 
unite(col="pathString",Start,Asset,Sub_Asset,Ticker,sep="-",remove=FALSE) %>%
select(-Start) %>% as.Node(pathDelimiter = "-")
 })

   output$radial <- renderRadialNetwork({
  # draw the radialNetwork with the specified size
  ToListExplicit(Data_tree(), unname = TRUE )
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The graphic should look like below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered the short coming in the code. Within the renderRadialNetwork function needed to add radialNetwork()

Here is the working final code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(networkD3)
library(data.tree)
library(tidyr)

# Define UI for application that draws a network graph
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("slate"),
     sliderInput("number",
                 "Random Numbers:",
                 min = 1,
                 max = 100,
                 value = 20),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  radialNetworkOutput("radial")
  )

 # Define server logic required to draw a network graph
 server <- function(input, output) {


  Data_tree <- reactive({
data.frame(Start="Class",
                      Asset = sample(c("FI","Equity","Currency"),input$number,replace = TRUE),
                      Sub_Asset = sample(c("Asia","Europe","USA"),input$number,replace = TRUE),
                      Ticker = replicate(input$number,paste0(sample(LETTERS,3),collapse=""))) %>% 
unite(col="pathString",Start,Asset,Sub_Asset,Ticker,sep="-",remove=FALSE) %>%
select(-Start) %>% as.Node(pathDelimiter = "-")
  })

   output$radial <- renderRadialNetwork({
  # draw the radialNetwork with the specified size
 radialNetwork(ToListExplicit(Data_tree(), unname = TRUE ), linkColour = "#ccc",nodeColour = "#fff",
               nodeStroke = "orange",textColour = "#cccccc")
    })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```